# Call API in Python to run Jenkins Job - problem with authentication

Tags: python, jenkins

I have got a Jenkins job which I can run with making a post request:

`curl -u albert405:{mytoken} http://172.31.32.33:8080/job/URL_Job_Trigger/build?token=ozSVoEQfLg`

Could you tell me how to place this authentication `(albert405:{mytoken})` into my Python script:

```
import requests

url = 'http://172.31.32.33:8080/job/URL_Job_Trigger/build?token=ozSVoEQfLg'


x = requests.post(url)

print(x.text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by this :

```
http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build
```

```
    import requests
    
    build = requests.post("http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build?token=TokenName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your authentication code? I see none of it.

Jenkins uses Basic Auth, which is indicated here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API.

In order to send auth parameters with requests it's a simple:

```
res =requests.post(url, auth=("albert405", "password"))
```

Which is the first documentation you get when googling `basic auth requests`: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/